# Add-RDServer : The server is joined to the deployment as a RD Session Host server. The following servers did not validate successfully

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop

Adding RDS-RD-SERVER role on xxxx machine using command:
`Add-RDServer -Role RDS-RD-SERVER -Server xxxx -ConnectionBroker yyyy`
Since the role is already installed, output of command is 
`Add-RDServer : The server is joined to the deployment as a RD Session Host server.`
`The following servers did not validate successfully.`
`xxxx`

Why the server xxxx is not validated successfully? What could be the reason for this? Thanks

Comment: Because it's already a member of the RDS deployment?

Comment: Question is that why server is not validated successfully, Thanks

Comment: I just said :) One of the things it's trying to validate is whether the server is eligible to join the deployment - if it's already a member, that validation obviously fails :)